# Как обратиться из JS файла ( который привязан к первому html файлу) ко второму HTML файлу?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть два файла index_1.html и index_2.html, а также app.js, который
подключен к index_1.html

Мне надо что-то типо обращения к index_2.html в app.js


*index_1.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>INDEX_1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js' > </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне надо что-то такое, чтобы стандартно был привязан к index_1.html, но можно было и обратится к index_2.html


*app.js*

```
document_1 = 'index_2.html'
document_1.write('Hello world')
```

Comment: Где при этом второй файл? Открыт ли он в браузере, или лежит просто как файл на сервере, как они вообще связаны? В чём отличие второй страницы от гугла например?

Comment: Если они никак не связаны, а просто мысленно вместе и открыты в браузере в разных вкладках, то никак. Пока вы не разместите скрипт и во втором файле. Тогда уже два скрипта могут общаться например через localStorage.